# is there something like a protocol for implementing indexers?

Tags: javascript, document-indexing, protocol, performance

I am currently developing a javascript API that uses Apache Tika for reading documents and then executes flexible search by using the flexsearch library. I am asking it because admittedly I am having big performance issues which seems related to the indexing and I don't know if it is necessarily trivial. Is there a way to export some functions related to the indexing and abstract some part of the implementation? It would be also interesting to have it running on the background as a server process